# How can i do it to put a comma in front of my last two numbers?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a textbox and would like to put a comma before the last two numbers! Someone help me out and describe how I should do it? Describe it as briefly as possible! Thanks in advance!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    textBox1.Text = int.Parse(szam1.Text) * int.Parse(szazalek1.Text) + "";
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eredmeny2.Text = int.Parse(szam2.Text) * int.Parse(szazalek2.Text) + "";
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. Without that, we can not help you.

Comment: I'd like to calculate the percentage! And Here's the code: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            textBox1.Text = int.Parse(szam1.Text) * int.Parse(szazalek1.Text) + "";
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    textBox1.Text = (int.Parse(szam1.Text) * int.Parse(szazalek1.Text)).ToString(); 
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eredmeny2.Text = "," + (int.Parse(szam2.Text) * int.Parse(szazalek2.Text)).ToString();
}
```

- for what is the '+ ""' in your code? For converting to string?
  Wrong. You should use '.ToString()' instead.
- if you want "," at the beginning of any string, simply add it
  before, like shown above.